# VS Code not responding properly to keyboard switch in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

In my Linux Mint OS, I have switched the `ESC` key with the `CAPS` key. I know that the switch has been made because it works properly for every other application. However, when it comes to VS Code, in particular, I still need to press the `ESC` key in order to escape from auto complete suggestions.